# How to get response on error in SUDS?

Tags: python, suds

If i have some bad authorization data (for example wrong password) SUDS rises exception `(400, u'Bad Request')` from which i cant get anything, but in teh log is response, which contains data that password is wrong, but how to get this response? I tried like this:

```
except Exception as e:

    print str(e)
    print self._client.last_received()
```

It prints:

```
(400, u'Bad Request')
None
```

But in log there is long xml which contains `<SOAP-ENV:Reason><SOAP-ENV:Text xml:lang="en">Sender not authorized</SOAP-ENV:Text></SOAP-ENV:Reason>`

Comment: How do you define `self._client`?

Comment: @Andy it is suds object

Comment: Can you show the `try` portion of your code then? What you've show is working for me using my own try block. Let's see what yours is doing

Comment: @Andy there a lot of code... The main problem is in exception... If i write right password `last_received` work fine, but when i do some mistakes it fails after exception.

Answer (score 2):

I am pulling this out of a comment and into an answer because of the code block.

```
import suds.client

try:
    auth_url = "https://url.to.my.service/authenticator?wsdl"
    auth_client = suds.client.Client(auth_url)
    cookie = auth_client.service.authenticate(user,password)
except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
    print auth_client.last_received()
```

Using this code, I receive the appropriate response from my service if I pass an invalid password:

```
Server raised fault: 'error.pwd.incorrect'
None
```

And an appropriate response if I pass an invalid user id:

```
Server raised fault: 'error.uid.missing'
None
```

Something you may want to consider doing, is changing your `except` statement to catch [`suds.WebFault`](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.WebFault-class.html) instead of the generic exception. There may be something else that is occurring and triggering your exception block.

One other thing that may help with your issue, is to pass [`faults=True`](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#FAULTS) in your `Client()` call.

> The Client can be configured to throw web faults as WebFault or to
>   return a tuple (, )

The code I posted above would look like this:

```
auth_client = suds.client.Client(auth_url, faults=True)
```

Comment: How is it not working? What is it doing vs. what do you expect?

Comment: `auth_client = suds.client.Client(auth_url, faults=True)` did not work for me. Still `auth_client.last_received()` gives me None.